# Let $\mathcal R$ be a $\sigma$-ring, then: $\{E\subset X; E\cap F \in \mathcal R\text{ for every } F \in \mathcal R\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm trying to Solve the following question:

> Let $X$ be a non empty set and  $\mathcal R$ be a  $\sigma$-ring from subset of $X$. Prove that: $$S=\{E\subset X; E\cap F \in \mathcal R\text{ for every } F \in \mathcal R\}$$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

I can show that $S$ is closed under the countable union of it's subsets. But how I can show that if $E\in S$, then $E^c \in S$?

Comment: "its" not "it's"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let: $E\in S$. For every $F\in \mathcal R$, we know that $E\cap F \in \mathcal R$. So, $F-(E\cap F) \in \mathcal R$. And it's easy to see that, $E^c \cap F=F-(E\cap F)$. Thus, $E^c \cap F \in \mathcal R$. So, $E^c\in S$.

Comment: Why is $F-(E\cap F)\in \mathcal R$?  What is your definition of $\sigma$-ring?

Comment: Real Analysis by Folland (page 24-exercise 1)

Comment: I'd prefer not to purchase a book to know your definition.  There are multiple definitions, the most basic is "closed under countable union".

Comment: please give a reference for your definition  from $\sigma-$ring.

Comment: Folland says a ring is closed under finite unions and differences.